# Need some help with a Deployment issue within maas ,Maas is already installed and all compute nodes are in a ready state , mdadm error

Tags: maas

This is the Error i receive when the deployments runs, is this a permission error or multipath issue ? , i have tried many unsuccessful fixes

Current device storage tree:
sda
|-- md127
`-- md126 sdb |-- md127` -- md126
Shutdown Plan:
{'level': 3, 'device': '/sys/class/block/md127', 'dev_type': 'raid'}
{'level': 3, 'device': '/sys/class/block/md126', 'dev_type': 'raid'}
{'level': 1, 'device': '/sys/class/block/sda', 'dev_type': 'disk'}
{'level': 1, 'device': '/sys/class/block/sdb', 'dev_type': 'disk'}
shutdown running on holder type: 'raid' syspath: '/sys/class/block/md127'
Running command ['mdadm', '--query', '--detail', '--export', '/dev/md127'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Discovering raid devices and spares for /sys/class/block/md127
Wiping superblock on raid device: /sys/class/block/md127
wiping superblock on /dev/md127
wiping /dev/md127 attempt 1/4
wiping 1M on /dev/md127 at offsets [0, -1048576]
/dev/md127 (size=0): 1048576 bytes from 0 > size. Shortened to 0 bytes.
/dev/md127 (size=0): invalid offset -1048576. Skipping.
successfully wiped device /dev/md127 on attempt 1/4
Removing raid array members: ['/dev/sda', '/dev/sdb']
mdadm mark faulty: /dev/sda in array /dev/md127
Running command ['mdadm', '--fail', '/dev/md127', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Non-fatal error clearing raid array: mdadm: set device faulty failed for /dev/sda:  No such device

mdadm mark faulty: /dev/sdb in array /dev/md127
Running command ['mdadm', '--fail', '/dev/md127', '/dev/sdb'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Non-fatal error clearing raid array: mdadm: set device faulty failed for /dev/sdb:  No such device

using mdadm.mdadm_stop on dev: /dev/md127
mdadm stopping: /dev/md127
mdadm: stop on /dev/md127 attempt 0
/sys/class/block/md127/md/sync_action/sync_max =
mdadm: setting array sync_action=idle
mdadm: (non-fatal) write to /sys/class/block/md127/md/sync_action failed [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sys/class/block/md127/md/sync_action'
/sys/class/block/md127/md/sync_max/sync_max =
mdadm: setting array sync_{min,max}=0
mdadm: (non-fatal) write to /sys/class/block/md127/md/sync_max failed [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sys/class/block/md127/md/sync_max'
Running command ['mdadm', '--manage', '--stop', '/dev/md127'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
mdadm stop failed, retrying
/proc/mdstat:
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md126 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sda[1] sdb[0]
222703616 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : inactive sdb1 sda0
10402 blocks super external:imsm

Comment: Your blob is hard to read. Please [edit] your Question and apply "code formatting". Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].